# Need Help to retrieve studies with image streaming in clearcanvas workstation

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

We need Help to retrieve studies with image streaming in [ClearCanvas](http://clearcanvas.github.io/) workstation.
How to retrieve studies in ClearCanvas workstation from ClearCanvas servers with image streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming between the ClearCanvas ImageServer and ClearCanvas Workstation does not allow for storing of the streamed images in the workstation after they have been loaded in the viewer.  Through streaming, a study is loaded transiently, and then removed from memory after the viewer has been closed.

In order to configure the workstation to allow streaming on the server, simply add the ImageServer as a Device, entering the proper hostname and port of the Server Partition on the ImageServer you want to connect to.  You must also click the checkbox that enables streaming, the default ports for header and image streaming should be correct.  Then, query the device to show the studies on the device, select one study, and double click the study to start streaming it, or select the "Open" button for the study.  Either will open the study in "streaming" mode where it will stream the header information and the images from ImageServer.